# Reliably forcing a backgrounded app to terminate due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, ios7, memory-pressure

I am trying to understand the conditions that cause the iOS system to relaunch an app that has been terminated due to memory pressure. Creating enough memory pressure has been hard though.

Currently my approach is to launch my app via Xcode, background it, and launch a helper app that eats memory. It allocates bits of memory in an NSTimer loop until the iOS system kills it. When I am lucky, Xcode tells me that my main app was "Terminated due to Memory Pressure".

I am looking for a more reliable way to achieve this. Are there memory allocation techniques or private APIs that are better for this purpose?

Comment: Give your app to my wife ... guaranteed crash.

Comment: @Rob - the helper app receives the didReceiveMemoryWarning message and the iOS system kills the helper app shortly after, but not the main app. I am testing on a 5s.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little surprised by the behavior you describe, but a few thoughts:

1. As far as I know, iOS makes no assurances regarding the order that apps are jettisoned nor guarantees that all background apps will be jettisoned (or whether it will just try to jettison enough apps to relieve the memory pressure condition). The [Handling low memory conditions in iOS and Mavericks](http://www.newosxbook.com/articles/MemoryPressure.html) offers some clues, but I can't vouch for it. But the OS is engaging in some complicated logic, so I would hesitate to make any firm claims about the steps one must take to ensure that a particular apps is jettisoned.
2. This issue of the order of background apps being jettisoned would then be affected by the fact that you're allowing your helper app to crash. It's possible that background apps might not be jettisoned quickly enough to satisfy your helper app's allocation attempts. Thus, the helper app might be crashing before iOS gets around to jettisoning your main app.

   I might suggest a slightly different design of the helper app such that when it receives a memory warning, it releases all of the memory it requested and starts the process again. In my "Cause Memory Pressure" app, I actually wait a few seconds between stopping allocations when I receive the memory warning and the process of restarting the allocations.

   But, bottom line, I think you may want to make sure that the helper app doesn't crash, to make sure you fully exercise the memory pressure systems.
3. You describe waiting for the debugger in Xcode to report that the app is terminated. I might suggest repeating your experiment, running the main app directly on the device, but not through the debugger. I suggest this because it strikes me as theoretically possible that the fact that your app is attached to the debugger might actually affect the priority calculation in determining which apps are to be jettisoned.

   Since the app is going to be killed, there's no point in running it through the debugger anyway, because if the OS does something to restart the app (e.g. background `NSURLSession`, push notification, etc.), your debugging session would be gone anyway. So there's no point in running it through the debugger in order to observe the "what if the OS restarts my app" question.

   Personally, when diagnosing the behavior of apps being jettisoned, restarted, etc., I use the Xcode device Organizer, and observe the device's Console there. You can observe any of your app's NSLog statements in the console, as well as watching apps being jettisoned, your app be restarted (if the OS is indeed doing something to restart it), etc.

Comment: After trying all of your suggestions my helper app consumes memory until receiving a memory warning, frees all of it after a few seconds, and starts again but consumes 10% more the next time until the app crashes. I think the problem is the 5s has too much memory since it's really easy to get an iPod touch to jettison other apps but on the 5s I need to launch a few games and then run the helper app. I wish Apple made this easy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to accomplish is testing whether you've properly saved state so when relaunched you will navigate back to where you were.

What I'd suggest is having a flag set, so that when your app detects its been moved into the background, (applicationDidEnterBackground:), it asks for more time, does all the state changes, then either sits in a spin loop til killed, or executes `exit(0)'. You should be able to see that the app has "died" in Xcode, and you can then restart it.